# How to reduce double dots in path expressions using Java

Tags: java, regex, file, path, filepath

I am in the middle of making a Java application which in particular takes a relative file path of the form

```
String path = "path/to/Plansystem/Xslt/omraade/../../../Kms/Xslt/Rense/Template.xslt"
```

and reduce / simplify the path expression, so that it provides an equivalent path, but without the double dots. That is, we should obtain this String:

```
String result = "path/to/Kms/Xslt/Rense/Template.xslt"
```

Currently, I have defined the following Regular expression:

```
String parentDirectory = $/\/(?!\.)([\w,_-]*)\.?([\w,_-]*)\/\.\.\//$
```

I then replace any match with a single slash. This approach seems to work, and I came up with the expression using [Regexr.com](https://regexr.com), but it seems to me that my approach is a little hacky, and I would be surprised if this specific functionality is not available in some well tested, well developed library. Is anyone familiar with such a library?

Edit:
Based on the responses made by rzwitserloot and Andy Turner I realized that the following methods works for me:

```
public static String slash = "/"
public static final String backslashes = $/\\+/$

static String normalizePath(String first, String... more) {
      String pathToReturn = Paths.get(first, more).normalize().toString().replaceAll(backslashes, slash)
      return pathToReturn
}
```

Note that the replacement I make at the end is only due to a specific need I have, where I want to preserve the unix notation (even when running on Windows).

Comment: [Path.normalize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#normalize--)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, don't bother with regular expressions. There's an API for this!

Basic 'dot' removal:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;

Paths.get("/Users/Birdie/../../Users/Birdie/workspace/../workspace").normalize()
```

Will get you a path representing `/Users/Birdie/workspace`.

You can go further and follow softlinks, even:

```
Paths.get("/Users/Birdie/../../Users/Birdie/workspace/../workspace").toRealPath()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. How dependent is this on the underlying operating system (and its filesystem)? Will it produce the correct result on Windows despite it has a different file seperator?

Comment: By softlink, do you mean that there are dots in multiple sequences?

Comment: It almost works, but when I use it on Windows, slashes are converted to backslashes. I want for it to respect the notation it receives as an input.

Comment: That makes no sense; why 'preserve the input'? The fact that java lets you write `c:/foo/bar` at all is convenient but in the end weird. soft links are rare on windows, but you can create files not as a file but as a link to another, on linux: `ln -s /foo/bar/source /bar/baz/target`, which makes target appear, but it's a link that acts as a file. with fsutil you can make them on windows too.

Comment: The reason is that I (in my particular case) want to write an application using a HashMap<String, String>, where the keys are essentially file paths - and I want for the keys to use unix notation.

Comment: Ah, I now realize that my requirement is redundant. It is perfectly fine for the keys to vary depending on the operating system. My bad... But I still wonder why it is not easily possible. I was wondering if using the Zipfilesystem (which is another Java filesystem implementation) would do the trick since it seems to use the alternative notation.

Comment: This IS the 'easy' option. There is no easy option to do something that should never come up (remove double-dots but keep the wrong path separator), all as it should be.

Comment: Well... I know my use case is unconventionel. But here it is: I take a Zip file, make it into a ZipInputStream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and then I unfold the contents of the Zip into a HashMap<String,String> (as previously explained). And due to implementation reasons, each entry obtained from the stream has a path name which uses unix notation. I could alternatively convert these names, but in all cases my attempt was to make my application use the concept of path notation without being dependent on the Windows file system.

Comment: The application at no point loads an actual file, and for that reason I never use the Windows file system explicitly.

Comment: In that case, what you want is far too exotic for the core lib to cater to it. So, just.. rwite it yourself. You said you would be 'surprised', but, I think that surprise is misplaced: This job (remove dots) is exotic/uncommon; the common job is (canonicalize this path according to the local fs rules). That last one java does have.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`java.nio.Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html):

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/Plansystem/Xslt/omraade/../../../Kms/Xslt/Rense/Template.xslt");
Path normalized = path.normalize();
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that tomorrow.

Comment: It almost works, but when I use it on Windows, slashes are converted to backslashes. I want for it to respect the notation it receives as an input.

Comment: @Birdie [according to this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) (look for "Returns in Microsoft Windows"), a Windows path will be printed with `\\`.